# How to detect Ant build errors in nested Groovy script

Tags: ant, groovy

I have a build.xml with the following:

```
<project name="myProject>

    <target name="execGroovy">
        <groovy>
            def task = project.createTask('antcall')
            task.target = "taskTarget"
            task.perform()
        </groovy>
    </target>

    <target name="taskTarget">
        <!-- do some things here -->
    </target>

</project>
```

It appears that the script will crash silently if the `perform()` call fails. How can I prevent this and/or detect if the Ant target invoked from the Groovy script failed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation I found that you can surround groovy commands with try catch finally blocks, like so:

```
<project name="myProject>

    <target name="execGroovy">
        <groovy>
            def task = project.createTask('antcall')
            task.target = "taskTarget"
            try {
                task.perform()
            } catch(Exception e) {
                // do something appropriate
            }
        </groovy>
    </target>

    <target name="taskTarget">
        <!-- do some things here -->
    </target>

</project>
```